# how to create simulated censored dataset in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, probability, probability-theory

I would like to write a code to generate a dataset censored with 1 censored data point and varying percent censored. 
I have the following code to generate some random numbers but not censored

```
n=input('Enter sample size:');
GM=input('Enter geometric mean:'); 
GSD=input('Enter geometric standard deviation:');
m=input('Enter desired number of dataset:');
x = lognrnd(log(GM), log(GSD),n,m);
```

I have the following code to create a censored dataset with known a limit of detection (lod) value (LOD) and then calculate the percent censored value and there I have a dataset to work with.

```
c = (x > lod); % c are values less than this number 
x(c) = lod;  % create single lod
sum(c)/length(c) % calculate percent censored
```

but what I want to do it is to provide the computer the desired percent censored and have the computer find the lod corresponds to that percent censored.  I can manually put in the lod value but that takes very long time if i want to create a dataset with percent censored 5-95.

The goal is to create varying censored datasets with varying percent censored for a simulation. I've been doing it one dataset at a time and it's taking a very long time. Please let me know if this all makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Statistical Toolbox you can use functions [PRCTILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/prctile.html):

```
pct = 10;
lod = prctile(x, pct);
```

or [QUANTILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/quantile.html) (it actually uses prctile inside).

```
pct = 0.1;
lod = quantile(x,pct);
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to create simulated dataset with multiple censored values?   What I have right now is a simulation with a single  censored value.

Comment: What do you mean? If you do `c=x<lod` at certain `lod` you get a vector with multiple true values (censored). Or do you mean multiple censored vectors?

Comment: Thanks Yuk.  I got it!!! If I do  this x(c) = lod;, then I just created data with single LOD but if I just do c=x<lod and skip x(c) = lod, then I just created a dateset with multiple censored values.  Thank you for clarifying!!

Answer (score 0):

There is surely more than one way to approach this, but a very straightforward approach would be to use an estimated PMF and CMF based on the data.

If I want to determine a threshold so that a certain percentage of the data is below the threshold, I would approach it like this first:

```
%# Get a histogram of the data
nbins = 100;
[counts xout]=hist(x,nbins);
pmf = counts/length(x);
cmf = cumsum(pmf);

%# Determine the threshold based on some percentage
pct = 0.05;
idx = find(cmf<0.05,1,'last')
thold = xout(idx);

%# in this instance, 5% of the data is below x(idx)
%# now the data can be thresholded
thresholded = x(x>thold);
```